# IIS 10. Not getting detailed stack traces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, logging, stack-trace, http-status-code-500

I'm running an mvc project on a local development box with IIS7.  On this box I'm getting detailed stack traces when 500 errors occur in the event log.  However when I move the same code to a Server 2016 version of IIS 10, the event log messages only include the following text:

> The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.

When I add customerErrors Off to the web.config, then the IIS 10 event log includes detailed stack traces.  PDB files are getting deployed, and I have tested deploying in debug mode to the IIS 10 server.  Obviously I cannot deploy the project with customerErrors Off.  Is there some other configuration in IIS 10 that would allow detailed error messages to be reported?

SOLVED: Found in the project that the HandleErrorAttribute was being added in the FilterConfig file.  Additionally, there was no error view.  So it appears that when running on a remote server, when an error is generated, then the HandleErrorAttribute attempts to find the view, which is missing.  So the missing view generates an error itself, and the original error is not reported.

Comment: Why can't you deploy this with custom errors off? Is there some reason actual users would be able to find the new server address?

Comment: So, the 2016 box would be either a test or production server.  In that case we wouldn't want to risk exposing detailed error messages to external users.

Comment: How would the users get to this application? There are scenarios where this is possible, but in my typical scenarios new servers are only accessible by a special hosting link, or an IP until we point a domain to it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I added a note in above since I discovered that the HandleErrorAttribute with missing error view was masking the original error.  Thanks for considering this problem.